# C#_WPF: Movable button -> Separate Click action from Move action

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a Movable Floating action button in C# WPF.
By clicking on this button, Popup window gets open.

**Problem**
When I move the button, also popup window gets open.

**Please how could I separate those 2 actions? (moving the button and opening the popup window)**
I don't want to open the popup window when I'm moving the button.

Thank you very much.

**Class with mouse event handlers:**

```
public partial class MovableButton : ResourceDictionary
{
    private double deltaX;
    private double deltaY;
    private Point? buttonPosition;
    private TranslateTransform currentTranslateTransform;

    public void PreviewMouseDownEventHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = sender as UIElement;
        var container = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;

        if (this.buttonPosition == null)
        {
            this.buttonPosition = element.TransformToAncestor(container).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        }

        var mousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(container);
        this.deltaX = mousePosition.X - this.buttonPosition.Value.X;
        this.deltaY = mousePosition.Y - this.buttonPosition.Value.Y;
    }

    public void PreviewMouseUpEventHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = sender as UIElement;
        this.currentTranslateTransform = element.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
    }

    public void PreviewMouseMoveEventHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            var element = sender as UIElement;
            var container = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;
            var mousePoint = Mouse.GetPosition(container);

            var offsetX = (this.currentTranslateTransform == null ?
                this.buttonPosition.Value.X : this.buttonPosition.Value.X - this.currentTranslateTransform.X) + this.deltaX - mousePoint.X;
            var offsetY = (this.currentTranslateTransform == null ?
                this.buttonPosition.Value.Y : this.buttonPosition.Value.Y - this.currentTranslateTransform.Y) + this.deltaY - mousePoint.Y;

            element.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(-offsetX, -offsetY);

            // To Stop Bubbling of MouseMove event
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML Style:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                x:Class="SampleApp.MovableButton">

<Style x:Key="MovableFloatingActionButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="PreviewMouseDownEventHandler" />
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseUp" Handler="PreviewMouseUpEventHandler" />
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="PreviewMouseMoveEventHandler" />

    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#00CCCC" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#111111" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#000000" />
    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="20"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work.  My solution could use some improvements, but that's a separate exercise.

Basically in your code-behind, use your PreviewMouseDown/Up events to test if the user clicked within a certain threshold of pixels, or if they moved the control.  If the threshold is met (meaning, they want a popup), open the Popup control.  Otherwise, do nothing.

**Full Code:**

```
    <Style x:Key="MovableFloatingActionButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="PreviewMouseDownEventHandler" />
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseUp" Handler="PreviewMouseUpEventHandler" />
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="PreviewMouseMoveEventHandler" />

        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#00CCCC" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#111111" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#000000" />
        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="20" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Popup x:Name="myPopup" StaysOpen="False">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="White" Background="DarkGreen" Margin="15" FontSize="32">HERE'S MY POPUP</TextBlock>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

```
    public partial class MovableButton : ResourceDictionary
    {
        private double deltaX;
        private double deltaY;
        private Point? buttonPosition;
        private TranslateTransform currentTranslateTransform;
        private Point mouseDownPosition;
        private Point mouseUpPosition;
        private bool toggleOpen;

        // Threshold of 3 pixels, but you can make this whatever your want.
        private const double DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 3.0d;

        public void PreviewMouseDownEventHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = sender as UIElement;
            var container = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;

            if (this.buttonPosition == null)
            {
                this.buttonPosition = element.TransformToAncestor(container).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
            }

            this.mouseDownPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(container);
            this.deltaX = this.mouseDownPosition.X - this.buttonPosition.Value.X;
            this.deltaY = this.mouseDownPosition.Y - this.buttonPosition.Value.Y;
        }

        public void PreviewMouseUpEventHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = sender as UIElement;
            var container = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;
            this.currentTranslateTransform = element.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
            this.mouseUpPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(container);
            var distance = Point.Subtract(this.mouseUpPosition, this.mouseDownPosition).Length;

            if (distance < DISTANCE_THRESHOLD)
            {
                // Allow the popup to occur.
                var controlTemplate = ((Button)element).Template;
                var popup = (Popup)controlTemplate.FindName("myPopup", sender as FrameworkElement);
                toggleOpen = !toggleOpen;
                popup.IsOpen = toggleOpen;
            }
        }

        public void PreviewMouseMoveEventHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                var element = sender as UIElement;
                var container = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;
                var mousePoint = Mouse.GetPosition(container);

                var offsetX = (this.currentTranslateTransform == null ?
                    this.buttonPosition.Value.X : this.buttonPosition.Value.X - this.currentTranslateTransform.X) + this.deltaX - mousePoint.X;
                var offsetY = (this.currentTranslateTransform == null ?
                    this.buttonPosition.Value.Y : this.buttonPosition.Value.Y - this.currentTranslateTransform.Y) + this.deltaY - mousePoint.Y;

                element.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(-offsetX, -offsetY);

                // To Stop Bubbling of MouseMove event
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    <Grid Background="AliceBlue">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MovableFloatingActionButton}" Width="200" Content="Click Me"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped me.

I updated your IF statement in MouseUpEventHandler to make it more generic.
`((ButtonBase)element).Command.Execute(button.CommandParameter);`